# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client - How to solve it

Tags: node.js, express

It show error json in postman as expected but after that it crashed.

- It not get crashed after sending success json

DB connected
POST /api/signup 200 84.443 ms - 27
events.js:377
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
at ServerResponse.header (/home/aman/Projects/Discover/discover_blog/backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10)
at ServerResponse.send (/home/aman/Projects/Discover/discover_blog/backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:174:12)
at ServerResponse.json (/home/aman/Projects/Discover/discover_blog/backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:278:15)
at /home/aman/Projects/Discover/discover_blog/backend/controllers/auth.js:22:30
at /home/aman/Projects/Discover/discover_blog/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:5004:18
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
```

Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
at /home/aman/Projects/Discover/discover_blog/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:5006:15
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}

```
//

const User = require("../models/user");
const shortId = require("shortid");
//
const signup = (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  User.findOne({ email: email }).exec((err, user) => {
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Email is taken ",
      });
    }
  });

  let username = shortId.generate();
  let profile = `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/profile/${username}`;
  let newUser = new User({ name, email, password, profile, username });

  newUser.save((err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: err,
      });
    }
    return res.json({
      message: "Signup is successfull! Please signin",
      user: user,
    });
  });
};

module.exports = { signup };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running `newUser.save` too early - you need to wait until `.findOne` finishes, otherwise you're both sending the initial 400 status (that the email is taken) and then one with the signup results. I'd also recommend not ignoring the possible `.findOne` error.

```
const signup = (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;
    User.findOne({ email: email }).exec((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: err,
            });
        }
        if (user) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: "Email is taken ",
            });
        }
        const username = shortId.generate();
        const profile = `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/profile/${username}`;
        const newUser = new User({ name, email, password, profile, username });

        newUser.save((err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: err,
                });
            }
            return res.json({
                message: "Signup is successfull! Please signin",
                user: user,
            });
        });
    });
};
```